# The meaning of "to" in " to the dominant variants to increase their protection"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could someone help me understand the meaning of "to" in "to the dominant variants to increase their protection"? The complete paragraph is "[It suggests that the UK needs to continue vaccinating vulnerable age groups 'at regular periods with updated vaccines' to the dominant variants to increase their protection](https://news.sky.com/story/covid-19-new-deadlier-coronavirus-variant-a-realistic-possibility-sage-warns-12368798)." Shouldn't it be "for" instead of "to" in this context? Thank you!

Comment: Uh, I'm a native speaker, and I also can't make heads or tails out of this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, *vaccines for* would be better than *vaccines to*. *Vaccines **against*** would be even better.

Or the whole paragraph could be rewritten:

**It suggests that in order to increase their protection from the dominant variants, vulnerable age groups in the UK need to continue being vaccinated 'at regular periods with updated vaccines.'**

Comment: Thank you so very much for your detailed explanations!